# kubernetes force delete deployment

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a way where we can delete the kubernetes deployment forcefully.
We tried to delete but not sure which process is running to pop that deployment again after the deletion.

We are not sure which deployment file or config were used to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the deployment by utilizing the kubectl delete deploy command.

[image]

If your deployment was established through a higher-level controller such as Helm or Operators, it's essential to uninstall them. In the case of Helm, you can achieve this by executing the command "helm uninstall RELEASE_NAME".

You may consult the official documentation for detailed guidance on performing uninstallation of Helm releases using the [helm uninstal](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_uninstall/)l

You can also examine Kubernetes cluster events and logs to gain insight into what is causing the deployment to be recreated. This analysis might reveal the responsible controller or process.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I tried installation with make. but now make uninstall is not working properly. it is referring to registry.k8s.io/kustomize/kustomize:v3.8.9

Comment: what is the error message? What documentation are you referring to for installing 'make'?

Comment: https://open-policy-agent.github.io/gatekeeper/website/docs/install/

Comment: What is the error message? What deployment are you trying to delete?

Comment: make uninstall --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
docker run -v /tmp/gatekeeper-master/config:/config -v /tmp/gatekeeper-master/vendor:/vendor \
 registry.k8s.io/kustomize/kustomize:v3.8.9 build \
 /config/overlays/dev | kubectl delete -f -
Unable to find image 'registry.k8s.io/kustomize/kustomize:v3.8.9' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry.k8s.io/v2/": net/http: TLS handshake timeout.

Comment: Please try pulling the image manually from the registry to see if you have access. Please use the command "docker pull registry.k8s.io/kustomize/kustomize:v3.8.9"

Comment: I do not have access to pull from external registry. Is there any other way to uninstall gatekeeper? I tried to get kubernetes events but did not see what is triggering the deployments. I deleted the mutating and validating webhooks too still the deployment comes back after deletion. Even CRD's are coming back after deletion.

Comment: Did you try the following command?

kubectl delete -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/open-policy-agent/gatekeeper/v3.15.0/deploy/gatekeeper.yaml
cd gatekeeper
make uninstall         
helm delete gatekeeper --namespace gatekeeper-system
kubectl delete crd -l gatekeeper.sh/system=yes

Comment: I have copied gatekeeper.yaml on my server and ran kubectl delete -f gatekeeper.yaml. It shows that resources are deleted but when I do get deployments, I see all resources back again.  I am failing to understand which controller is recreating these resources.